# Update when dragged and resized Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, resize, drag

I got the jquery variables to update the height width and positions when the divs are dragged but I need them to do the same when they are resized....how can I do this?  Here is my code that I'm using right now to get the variables and send them to the php document:

```
<?
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='derekshull'");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$googlewebx = $rows['googlewebx'];
$googleweby = $rows['googleweby'];
$googlewebh = $rows['googlewebh'];
$googlewebw = $rows['googlewebw'];

$googleimagex = $rows['googleimagex'];
$googleimagey = $rows['googleimagey'];
$googleimageh = $rows['googleimageh'];
$googleimagew = $rows['googleimagew'];

$googlenewsx = $rows['googlenewsx'];
$googlenewsy = $rows['googlenewsy'];
$googlenewsh = $rows['googlenewsh'];
$googlenewsw = $rows['googlenewsw'];

$wikix = $rows['wikix'];
$wikiy = $rows['wikiy'];
$wikih = $rows['wikih'];
$wikiw = $rows['wikiw'];

$wolfx = $rows['wolfx'];
$wolfy = $rows['wolfy'];
$wolfh = $rows['wolfh'];
$wolfw = $rows['wolfw'];

$twitterx = $rows['twitterx'];
$twittery = $rows['twittery'];
$twitterh = $rows['twitterh'];
$twitterw = $rows['twitterw'];
?>

<html>
<head>


 <style>
  .resizable { color: white; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding: 0.1em; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
  .resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
  </style>


<style>
#set div.resizable {
    background: rgba(0, 157, 255, 0.9);
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;

    padding: 0.5em;
}
  #set { clear:both; float:left; width: 368px;}
  p { clear:both; margin:0; padding:1em 0; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<script>
function stop(ui, type) {
    var pos_x;
    var pos_y;
    var window_width;
    var window_height;
    var need;
    if (type == 'draggable') {
        pos_x = ui.offset.left;
        pos_y = ui.offset.top;
        window_width = window.innerWidth;
        window_height = window.innerHeight;
        need = ui.helper.data("need");
    } else if (type == 'resizable') {
        pos_x = $(ui.element).offset().left;
        pos_y = $(ui.element).offset().top;
        window_width = window.innerWidth;
        window_height = window.innerHeight;
        need = ui.helper.data("need");
    }

    var width;
    var height;

    if (need == 1) {
        width = $("#web").width();
        height = $("#web").height();
    }

    if (need == 2) {
        width = $("#image").width();
        height = $("#image").height();
    }

    if (need == 3) {
        width = $("#wiki").width();
        height = $("#wiki").height();
    }

    if (need == 4) {
        width = $("#twitter").width();
        height = $("#twitter").height();
    }

    if (need == 5) {
        width = $("#googlenews").width();
        height = $("#googlenews").height();
    }

    if (need == 6) {
        width = $("#wolf").width();
        height = $("#wolf").height();
    }

    console.log(pos_x);
    console.log(pos_y);
    console.log(width);
    console.log(window_width);
    console.log(need);

    //Do the ajax call to the server
    alert(' x:' + pos_x +
        ' y:' + pos_y +
        ' ned_id:' + need +
        ' width:' + width +
        ' height:' + height +
        ' window_width:' + window_width +
        ' window_height:' + window_height);
}

$("#set div").draggable({
    stack: "#set div",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: $('#main_content'),
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        stop(ui, 'draggable');
    }
});

$(".resizable").resizable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        stop(ui, 'resizable');
    }
});
</script>




<meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>
<title>15:11 Project | You • Your Community • Your World</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action='' method='post'>
<fieldset><center>
<input type='search' name='q' /><input type='submit' value='Search' name='submit' />
</fieldset></center>
</form>


<div id="main_content" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width:100.8%; margin:0 auto; height:95.1%; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;">

<div id="set">





<?
if(isset($_POST['q'])){
?>
<div id='web' style='overflow:hidden; left: 5%; top: 5%; width: 20%; height: 15%; position:fixed !important;' class='resizable ui-widget-content' data-need='1'>
<?php

enter code here for div 1.

echo "</div>";
}
?>









<?
if(isset($_POST['q'])){
?>
<div id='image' style='overflow:hidden; height: 19%; width: 32%; left: 60%; top: 12%; position:fixed !important;' class='resizable ui-widget-content' data-need='2'><center>
<?php

Enter code here for div 2
echo "</center></div>";
}
?>








<?
if(isset($_POST['q'])){
?>
<div id='wiki' style='overflow:hidden; left: 5%; top: 36%; height: 17%; width: 25%; position:fixed !important;' class='resizable ui-widget-content' data-need='3'>
<?php

Enter div 3.
}
?>
</div>



</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a function to the stop event...

```
$(function() { 
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
        stop: function(){
            // Do your updates here
        }
    }); 
});
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zkDHJ/

Comment: I updated my code but that did not work.  It made it not even give the resize option.  Could still drag it though.

Comment: I've added a fiddle with the working code.  You must have an issue somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Resizable function has the same event stop and you can create a function to do what you are doing in draggable stop and call it from resizable stop

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop

```
$(function() { 
 $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
  stop: function() {
   // call the same function as in draggable event stop
  }
 });
});
```

I would recommend creating a function to call from both events such as

```
function stop(ui, type) {
 // your code
}
```

And then call it from both events:

```
$( ".resizable" ).resizable({
 stop: function(event, ui) {
  stop(ui, 'resizable');
)};

$( ".draggable" ).resizable({
 stop: function(event, ui) {
  stop(ui, 'draggable');
 }
)};
```

EDIT: You see can see this jsfiddle showing you code working:
http://jsfiddle.net/v8efG/1/

There's a difference from the objects returned by draggable and resizable.

Draggable contains an offset property you can just use. Take a look at the wiki:

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

And Resizable does not contain offset but it contains element and you can obtain the offset from it. Take a look at the wiki:

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop

When draggable

```
pos_x = ui.offset.left;
```

When resizable

```
pos_x = $(ui.element).offset().left;
```

Comment: I updated my code but that did not work. It made it not even give the resize option. Could still drag it though.

Comment: It'll resize now but it won't save the position and size like it does when it's dragged.

Comment: please update your code to see if you have any other problem since the code is the same it should work either way.

Comment: I updated the code I have in my script.  It made them not able to drag or resize.  Also I added the divs in the body.  There are 6 total divs...I only posted the first 2.

Comment: you are closing after the stop function with a ); you should not do that. Take them out and it should work.

Comment: There is a difference from the object returned by draggable and resizable, resizale doesn't contain the offset property, you need to have different methods to get the offset of the element, when draggablejust use offset.left but in resizable user $(ui.element).offset().left, will update the code.

Comment: Check the latest fiddle to see the difference.

Comment: I did. It's so strange its exactly as you have it

Comment: Does it work for you in the jsfiddle because I have it to alert the values that you pass to the ajax method, if it is not working it might be something wrong server side.

Comment: Does the jsfiddle alert you correctly when dragging and resizing? Update your code to what you're using please.

Comment: Try putting the draggable and resizeable inside $(function(){ // your code here });